# Sails.js search by computed property

Tags: sails.js

I'm writing API in sails.js and I have one problem with finding objects.

I have model with attributes:

```
  attributes: {
    firstName:{
      type:"string",
      required:true,
      minLength: 2
    },

    lastName:{
      type:"string",
      required:true,
      minLength: 2
    },

    getFullName: function (){
      var fl =  this.firstName + " " + this.lastName;
      return fl;
    },
  }
```

And right now I would like to find a object with getFullName startsWith "xyz qwe"

How can I do it?

I have tried:

`Patient.find({ getFullName: { 'startsWith': 'Tomas' }}).exec(console.log)`

and

`Patient.find({ getFullName(): { 'startsWith': 'Tomas' }}).exec(console.log)`

and both are not working.

Can I access computed property like getFullName in find() function?

Of course this query is working:

`Patient.find({ firstName: { 'startsWith': 'Tomas' }}).exec(console.log)`

Answer (score 0):

`exec` or callback has 2 arguments (like any other callback), it's `error` and `result`. So your code should be like.

```
Patient
  .find({ getFullName: { 'startsWith': 'Tomas' }})
  .exec(function(err, founds){
    if(err) return console.error(err);

    console.log(founds);
  });
```

Or you can use Promise chaining to do what you did before.

```
Patient
  .find({ getFullName: { 'startsWith': 'Tomas' }})
  .then(console.log)
  .catch(console.error);
```

Comment: It's not a problem: `.exec(console.log)` works fine. The question is: how to use computed property (instance function) in find() method.   Btw. I'm testing it in `sails console` that's why I'm using `.exec(console.log)`

Comment: Sorry my bad, I misunderstood your question. I'll edit my answer later when I have time and if it still not solved.

Comment: I have solved it by complex find query. But my problem is more complicated than in my question, please, let me know about your solution for that problem. I hope it'll be better than mine.